What is the fundamental difference between := and = operators?
I was studying discrete mathematics and I came across the assignment operator ":=" so I made a quick search and found both of these questions:
What does := mean?
What's the difference among the logical relations :=, =, and ≡?
I scrolled for answers but didn't find one including the information to satisfy my curiosity knowing the fundamental difference.
Simply what I understood was that ":="(assignment operator) defines what is on the left-hand side to be equal to the statement on the right-hand side, while "="(equality operator) states that the left-hand equals the right-hand.
So my question here what is the fundamental difference between stating that l.h.s equals r.h.s and defining the l.h.s to be equal r.h.s?

:= means we are defining the left-hand side to be the right-hand side. The other kind of equality is mostly used to make an assertion (that asserts an equation between two things whose meaning has been given beforehand).

Any hard-and-fast definition you come across for these operators needs to be considered in the context in which you find the statements being made.

Usually (at least in sources which make the distinction at all, which is by no means universal), $:=$ is used when you're introducing a new variable, while $=$ is used when you're asserting equality of two expressions in terms of preexisting variables (and it could happen that the left hand side expression is just a single variable).

As per answer to the post linked, usually $:=$ stand for "definitional" equality while $=$ is (usual) mathematical equality: the two symbolic  expressions at the left and the right of the symbol are two ways to denote the same objects. Consider $1+1=2$: if we compute the LHS we get as result the RHS.

See here for the $:=$ symbol, mainly used "for naming a mathematical object, abbreviation of the phrase 'let $x:=E$', where $E$ is an expression and $x$ is a variable. This is similar to the concept of assignment in computer science." It is a modern "evolution" of $x=_{\text{Df}}E$ or $x=E \text { Df}$ (see PM notation) more suitable for coding.

A definition "legislates" about a term (name, symbol) while an assertion in math is either an axiom or a theorem. The definition "2 is the successor of 1" introduces a new symbol that we will use to name the number that is the successor of 1, while the formula $1+1=2$ states a fact about numbers, and we prove it.

As I asume you are searching for a more "logical" answer, I'd say $y:=x$ is the definition of $y$, something that can't be proven or disproven, and $y=x$ is a proposition, something that could be either false or true, something that involves two "known" elements.

Although other peers provided good answers, I accepted this one as it's simple as well as descriptive, and straight to the point, thanks.

Thank you! Hope it helps!

I regularly use $:=$ (\coloneq) in order to state an assignment by my own definition, it is more than a mere equivalence relation since it also suggests that we will take advantage of it by invoking the first term rather than the second one (e.g., the description of Figure 1 here uses the $:=$ symbol to indicate that $C(3,k)$ is a cleaner way to indicate the lattice $\{0,1,2\}^k$).

You will find that "$:=$" defines the left-hand side to be syntactically the same as the right-hand side.  Note that this can be temporal, since assignment can be repeated with inequivalent right-hand sides.  For instance, it is valid to have "$a := 1$" and (without intervening redefinitions of "$a$" or "$1$") later "$a := a+1$" -- where the "$a$" on the right-hand side is bound to "$1$" and the "$a$" on the left-hand side (and subsequent "$a$"s until re-assignment) are bound to "$1+1$".
In many contexts, "$=$" is overloaded to mean both assignment and equality.  This is common in math, and uncommon in programming.  For example, most/many C-like languages have "=" for assignment and "==" for equality.
In a context where assignment is not signified with "$=$", an equality is a (logical) statement that the values of the left-hand and right-hand sides are the same.  Continuing the example above, $a = 2$ would be a true statement, since $1+1$ and $2$ have equivalent values (and we assume the expressions and symbols are evaluated in the whole/natural/integer numbers since no alternative setting has been announced).
